# gclient sync error: No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpRcl2od/LICENSE'.What is the '/tmp/tmpRcl2od/LICENSE' used for?

Tags: android, webrtc

I am making the Android WebRtc source code on Ubuntu 14.4.When I enter the gclient sync,the errors occur:

```
Failed to fetch file gs://chromium-android-tools/play-services/10.2.0/31843001b7ce94fbdf71f2a9db76b28548a795fa for /tmp/tmpRcl2od/LICENSE, skipping. [Err: Failure: Server presented certificate that does not match host www.googleapis.com:
....

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpRcl2od/LICENSE'
Error: Command '/usr/bin/python src/build/android/play_services/update.py download' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/jack/workdir
```

Comment: Delete the whole directory and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have ended up in some kind of corrupted state in your checkout. 
I suggest trying to wipe `third_party/android_tools/sdk/extras/google/m2repository`
and manually run

```
/usr/bin/python build/android/play_services/update.py download --force
```

See https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/build/android/play_services/update.py for details on that script, if needed.
Worst case you might have to start over entirely, but I don't think that should be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.When I start over to execute the "fetch --nohooks webrtc_android", I get another error:
Your current directory appears to already contain, or be part of, 
a checkout. "fetch" is used only to get new checkouts. Use 
"gclient sync" to update existing checkouts.  I have removed the old checkout，but it still makes no sense. Could you give me more tips?

Comment: Create a new directory to start over in. When you run fetch it will create a .gclient file (which you won't see unless you do ls -l). I suspect that's why it detects why it's already "a part of a checkout".

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by add environment variable:

export BOTO_CONFIG=/path/to/boto.proxy